# Character animation using image array

Tags: java, arrays, animation

I have a problem animating my character's movement in my game. I'm using an image array of 16 elements.

The first cycle goes down well but after that the character doesn't animates. It moves but doesn't change the image just showing the first element of that cycle. If I change direction one cycle goes down again well and stops the same way.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public void paintHero(Graphics g) {
    // paint character
    offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);
    // show first image of the cycle where the character stands
    if (hero.getMoveX() == 0 && hero.getMoveY() == 0)
        heroFrame = 0;
    else {
        heroFrame++;
        if (heroFrame == 16)
            heroFrame = 0;
        // I'm dividing heroFrame by 4 to slow down the animation
        if (hero.isMovingUp() == true)
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[4 + heroFrame / 4];
        if (hero.isMovingDown() == true)
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[0 + heroFrame / 4];
        if (hero.isMovingLeft() == true)
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[8 + heroFrame / 4];
        if (hero.isMovingRight() == true)
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[12 + heroFrame / 4];
    }
}
```

Comment: won't change how anything is working but you don't need to do `hero.isMovingUp() == true`. `if(hero.isMovingUp())` will work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work but to be hosest doesn't really know why it is working now. I added draw after each if statement and kept the first one as well. If someone could explain it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void paintHero(Graphics g) {

    offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);

    if (hero.getMoveX() == 0 && hero.getMoveY() == 0)
        heroFrame = 0;
    else {
        heroFrame++;
        if (heroFrame == 16)
            heroFrame = 0;
    }

    if (hero.isMovingUp()) {
        heroCurrent = heroSprites[4 + heroFrame / 4];
        offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);
    }
    if (hero.isMovingDown()) {
        heroCurrent = heroSprites[0 + heroFrame / 4];
        offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);
    }
    if (hero.isMovingLeft()) {
        heroCurrent = heroSprites[8 + heroFrame / 4];
        offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);
    }
    if (hero.isMovingRight()) {
        heroCurrent = heroSprites[12 + heroFrame / 4];
        offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the sprites when no direction is changed. It should be:

```
public void paintHero(Graphics g) {
    // paint character
    offG.drawImage(heroCurrent, hero.getHeroX(), hero.getHeroY(), this);

    //always update frame
    heroFrame++;
    if (heroFrame == 16)
        heroFrame = 0;

    // show first image of the cycle where the character stands
    if (hero.getMoveX() == 0 && hero.getMoveY() == 0)
        heroCurrent = heroSprites[heroFrame];//update even if character isnt moving
    else {
        // I'm dividing heroFrame by 4 to slow down the animation
        if (hero.isMovingUp())
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[4 + heroFrame / 4];
        else if (hero.isMovingDown())
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[0 + heroFrame / 4];
        else if (hero.isMovingLeft())
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[8 + heroFrame / 4];
        else if (hero.isMovingRight())
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[12 + heroFrame / 4];
        else//stand still
            heroCurrent = heroSprites[heroFrame];
    }
}
```

Comment: With your answer before edit it was still the same unfortunately. Only one cycle went through. After the edit now I get IndexOutOfBound when moving right because it tries to access heroSprites[16].

Comment: @Kokufuu How about now?

Comment: Now it's spining continously around when it should stand still... :D And when it is moving it is the same issue still.